# Is there a dataflow trigger that fires after the window session is complete?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I use Google Cloud PubSub and Dataflow to handle my data. I would like to detect when my daily process is done, in other word when the window session is complete/gap duration is reached. Is there a single trigger that could be fired for this case? If not, is there a workaround I could use?

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    p.apply("ReadPubSubMessage", PubsubIO.readMessages().fromSubscription("projects/project-id/subscriptions/my-sub"))
            .apply("ApplyTimestamps", WithTimestamps.of((PubsubMessage pubSub) -> new Instant(System.currentTimeMillis())))
            .apply("SessionWindowing", Window.<PubsubMessage>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(10)))
                    .triggering(?)
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
                    .apply(new CountWords())
```

Sorry if I missed something obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, your window ends when the gap duration is reached (per [sessions definition](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Sessions.html)). Because of that, you can use the [Default Trigger](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers), since you have bounded windows, it will fire only once. Does that make sense?

Here you can find the DefaultTrigger [official documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/DefaultTrigger.html).

Comment: Thanks Mike for your reply. Well, in my understanding this is not a bounded windows but a dynamic one which should be complete after the gap duration of inactivity. When trying the DefaultTrigger, the trigger never gets fired.

Comment: Hi Gwendal, I think you’re right your Windows are dynamic, because they are not defined by a fixed time interval, but by the inactivity gap. I said “Bounded” because the [Sessions](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Sessions.html) class extends [WindowFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.html)  which extends [BoundedWindow](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/BoundedWindow.html).

Comment: Regarding the default trigger, can you let me know how you are writing it in your code? I found this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TopWikipediaSessions.java) which uses Sessions and the triggering condition is not explicitly set (thus using the Default Trigger), perhaps it can be useful for you.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the belated reply. We managed to do it at the end by counting globally the number of message(s) in a specific dataflow branch on a 20 minutes duration timeframe through the following trigger:
triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(WINDOWS_DURATION))).
The tricky part is that our dataflow is calling itself with a specific custom message. This means at the end of the 20 minutes, if we only have one message (our custom one), our window is complete. We will write an article on the issues we faced and solution we implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DefaultTrigger.of() trigger , I have put an example code below. 
Please note that It does not work in DirectRunner but will work in Google Dataflow.

```
PCollection<KV<String, FormMessageMeta>> formMetaSessionWindowCollection = formMessageMetaKvCollection.apply(
            "Session-Window",
            Window.<KV<String, FormMessageMeta>>into(
                    Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(40)))
            .triggering(DefaultTrigger.of()) 
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).accumulatingFiredPanes());
```

Session window can only be applied on KV.